# Is there a word or personality complex for someone who enjoys the things that they are the worst at?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if someone played three sports, football, baseball, and basketball. They were really good at football and baseball, but they were terrible at basketball. However, they choose to quit football and baseball to pursue basketball. Is there a personality complex that fits this description?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: That would depend on why they had made this choice.  Also, by the way, it is seriously difficult to imagine that some one who plays the two games you mention, which requires skills both with foot and hand would be such a duffer at basketball.

Comment: They could enjoy the challenge, or they could have deep psychological issues which cause them to need to fail. A quick Google suggests there could be something interesting on this topic, maybe even research, but the question definitely needs improvement to meet the standards for English SE. (And you might be better asking on psychology SE if you're interested in the phenomenon not the word.)

Comment: If he quits football and baseball to focus on basketball, he might be **perfectionist**. But, he may either be a  a **masochist**

Comment: @StuartF Even if they're just interested in the word, it's often best to ask in technical sites for industry-specific terminology.

Comment: The appropriate word will depend on why they want to do this. Alternative to being a masochist, they could just enjoy the challenge of activities they're not great in, because they're bored with the ones they're good at.

Comment: You remind me of the "America's Got Talent" judges who have to listen to auditioning singers who cannot sing. The contestants truly think they can sing. The truth is: They cannot! Perhaps they find joy in singing. Said a critic of a woman's singing,“I couldn't help thinkin' if she was as far out o' town as she was out o' tune, she wouldn't get back in a day.” The same could be said for the lousy basketball player who seems to come alive when he is doing something he loves to do, despite his lack of talent.